# Ruby on Rails - Preserve data on form builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using an form builder, but I need extra fields that are not included on my model. So I add it using an text_field_tag, but when I validate the form and it's an error present, the form its refreshed with the error messages and the value of those text_field_tag are loose. What's the right way to do it and preserve the data?

My form builder:

```
<%= form_for @brand do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= text_field_tag :description %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller:

```
params[:description] ||= ""
```

In your form:

```
<%= text_field_tag :description, params[:description] %>
```